# Error in layout with eclipse & android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have an activity with this layout

[image: http://s1.postimg.org/fg78eihbj/image.png]

(the upper side is a listview now empty).

I change the layout to obtain this (eclipse view).

[image: http://postimg.org/image/69oxr8c2z/]

The code:

```
<!-- layout-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">  

<!-- Create new deck -->
<TextView   
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/new_deck"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<!-- Deck name -->
<TextView   
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/deck_name" />

<!-- Description -->
 <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/description" />

 <!-- primo edit text -->
<EditText   
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:inputType="textCapSentences">

</EditText>

<!-- secondo edit text -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences" >

</EditText>

<!-- button create -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="@string/create" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1""
</ListView>
```

But on the phone the layout does't change and remain the same of first screenshot.
Obviously there is an error in the code but i can't find it

Comment: Change your ListView height to wrap_content

Comment: Looks fine on my preview if you close the root relative layout.

Comment: My mistake in the copy of the code I forgot to copy the end tag and changing to wrap content doesn't change anything

Comment: Never use `wrap_content` for the height of a `ListView`.

Comment: Your `ListView` seemed not set with any relative parameters like `layout_below`?

Comment: wrap_content, fill_parent, match_parent: the layout never change and i also notice that at the start of the activity editText1 gain focus and i never wrote code about focus in this activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <!-- Create new deck -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/new_deck"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<!-- Deck name -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/deck_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Description -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/description" />

    <!-- secondo edit text -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- button create -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/create" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ndroid:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```